# SQLResultSetMapping is throwing exception in case of null columns

Tags: java, eclipselink, jpa-2.1

I've got a value object for which i want to map my native query resultset.
I'm using `@SQLResultSetMapping` to map object fields but when value of any column is `null`, exception is throw:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-6177] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The column result [custom_properties] was not found in the results of the query.
```

My Entity Class and Mapping

```
@Entity
@Multitenant(MultitenantType.TABLE_PER_TENANT)
@Table(name = "account_master")
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "DTO_MAPPING", classes = @ConstructorResult(
    targetClass = AccountDTO.class,
    columns = {@ColumnResult(name = "id"),
        @ColumnResult(name = "name"),
        @ColumnResult(name = "custom_properties")
    })
)
public class Account implements Serializable {
// fields, setters and getters

}
```

Value Object:

```
public class AccountDTO {

  public AssetDTO(){
  }

  public AssetDTO(int id, String name, String customProperties) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.customProperties = customProperties;
  }

}
```

And the execution statement

```
List<AccountDTO> accList = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT id, name, custom_properties FROM account_master WHERE acc_hierarchy <@ 2.3", "DTO_MAPPING").getResultList()
```

If custom_properties (which is nullable) is replaced by a static value in query, mapping works  perfectly fine. Is there something wrong with the implementation? As mapping null value seems like a common scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was submitted as a bug in EclipseLink: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=484276

As a workaround, you can specify the type in the

> @ColumnResult

annotation.

So you should change your code to:

```
@Entity
@Multitenant(MultitenantType.TABLE_PER_TENANT)
@Table(name = "account_master")
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "DTO_MAPPING", classes = @ConstructorResult(
    targetClass = AccountDTO.class,
    columns = {@ColumnResult(name = "id"),
        @ColumnResult(name = "name"),
        @ColumnResult(name = "custom_properties", type=String.class)
    })
)
public class Account implements Serializable {
// fields, setters and getters

}
```

Comment: It worked! Now that I think about it, class type information of constructor arguments would be needed to get appropriate construction via reflection. Nullable columns need to mention it expicitly for jpa to work. It might not be a bug after all.